# Dimension of $L^2(E, \mathcal{E}, \mu)$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces

In my functional analysis course we showed (as a consequence of Stone-Weierstraß) that $L^2([0,1], \lambda)$ has countable (Hilbert space) dimension.

I wondered if we can deduce anything about the dimension of $L^2(E, \mathcal{E}, \mu)$ for a given measure space if we have some information about $(E, \mathcal{E}, \mu)$, such as ($\sigma$-)finiteness or $E$ being a compact space with $\mathcal{E} = \mathcal{B}(E)$ for example.

Comment: If $E$ is compact then $L^2(E)$ is separable. (I don't know what's your convention about "Hilbert space dimension", but $L^2(E)$ being separable means that you can find a countable set with a dense span)

Comment: @yanko Ok, that's interesting. So this doesn't depend on the measure at all if $E$ is compact?

Comment: good point. It should work for a finite measure.. I don't know about other measures.

Comment: I googled, and I believe you will be interested in this question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42310/when-is-l2x-separable It tells you when $L^2(X)$ is separable (hence of countable dimension).

Comment: @yanko Well the counting measure on an infinite and compact space does that. But I guess it's a matter of opinion if the counting measure is "non-conventional" :-)

Comment: The counting measure on an infinite compact space is definitely non-conventional haha.

Comment: Thanks for the link, that's indeed very interesting

Comment: @yanko If $E$ is compact then $L^2(E)$ is separable? That depends on what you're assuming about the measure...

Comment: @yanko In particular, assuming $\mu$ is a finite regular Borel measure is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

It's not true that if $E$ is compact then $L^2(E)$ is separable, without additional assumptions. Assuming that $\mu$ is a finite regular Borel measure is not enough:

Let $G=\{1,-1\}$. Regard $G$ as a compact group in the obvious way. Now for some  large set $I$ let $E=G^I$. Formally $E$ is the set of all functions from $I$ to $G$; to avoid confusion with the functions in $L^2$ we will write the elements of $E$ as $x=(x_i)_{i\in I}$.

Now $E$ is a compact abelian group,  and so its Haar measure $\mu$ is finite; as usual we normalize the Haar measure so $\mu(E)=1$.

For each $j\in I$ define $f_j:E\to\mathbb C$ by $$f_j(x)=x_j.$$ Then $\{f_j:j\in I\}$ is an orthonormal subset of $L^2(\mu)$, of cardinality $|I|$. That is, cardinality as large as you like, just start with $I$ large enough.

**Details** on why the $f_j$ are orthonormal: First, it's clear that $||f_j||_2=1$, since $|f_j(x)|=1$ for all $x$.

For $j\in I$ let $E_j=\{x:x_j=1\}$, $F_j=\{x:x_j=-1\}$. Define $y\in E$ by $y_i=-1$ if $i=j$, $y_i=1$ if $i\ne j$. Then $F_j=yE_j=\{yx:x\in E_j\}$, so since $\mu$ is translation-invariant we have $\mu(E_j)=\mu(F_j)$; since $E_j$ and $F_j$ are disjoint with union $E$ it follows that $\mu(E_j)=\mu(F_j)=1/2$.

Now suppose that $j,k\in I$, $j\ne k$. Arguing as above shows that
$$\mu(E_j\cap E_k)=\mu(E_j\cap  F_k)=\mu(F_j\cap E_k)=\mu(F_j\cap F_k)=1/4,$$so $$\int_E f_jf_k=\mu(E_j\cap E_k)+\mu(F_j\cap  F_k)
-\mu(E_j\cap  F_k)-\mu(F_j\cap E_k)=0.$$

Comment: If the sigma algebra is countably generated and the measure is finite then $L^{2}$ is separable. The Borel sigma algebra of any separable metric space is countable generated.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy No doubt what you say is so. It's asserted above that if $E$ is compact then $L^2(E)$ is separable, without any other conditions - _that_ is _not_ so.

Comment: David, of course, your argument is correct and compactness is not good enough. I was only trying to give a sufficient condition for separability of $L^{2} (E)$.